# Matching multiple instances from end of the string

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex statement, but am obviously mis-understanding something. I've got a C# `StackTrace` and want to essentially crop the end of the string until I see the first instance of our namespace. Here is a section of the data to illustrate - with a manually positioned new line to illustrate where I'm trying to match to.

```
   at MooD.LandscapeExplorer.Controllers.LandscapeController.GetContextInstanceCount(BusinessContext context) in C:\Source\MooDEdge\Code\MooD16\MooD.LandscapeExplorer\Controllers\LandscapeController.cs:line 143
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__1`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MooD.LandscapeExplorer.Controllers.LandscapeController.ProcessContext(String[] types, String[] instances, QueryFilter[] filters) in C:\Source\MooDEdge\Code\MooD16\MooD.LandscapeExplorer\Controllers\LandscapeController.cs:line 125

   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
```

So I want to keep the first half, and remove the second half from the string. I've used a negative lookahead (I grabbed from another question, I don't really understand how it works), to match on anything other than `MooD`. Then I've stuck on an end of string `$`.

`(at (?!MooD).*)$`

At this point I thought all I needed to do was to add a `*` to match lots of the previous group, turning the regex into:

`(at (?!MooD).*)*$`

However this doesn't work as I expected when testing on https://regex101.com/. It still just matches the final instance. I've also tried adding in a new line detection, but that still only matches the final line:

`(at (?!MooD).*\n?)*$`

Could anyone explain how I can match the rest, and why this solution doesn't work?

Comment: Could you not just split the whole thing on the carriage return, then (working backwards) discard each line until you hit the on containing MooD? The regex seems overkill for what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match bottom part you can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
at (?:(?!MooD)[\s\S])*$
```

`(?:(?!MooD)[\s\S])*` will match 0 or more of any character while asserting that no character has `MooD` at next position.

`[\s\S]` will match any character including newline.

**PS:** It is safer to use word boundary:

```
at (?:(?!\bMooD\b)[\s\S])*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE6xI1/3)

Comment: I was going to accept based on the RegEx demo you linked to - then discovered JavaScript doesn't support the single line option :(

Comment: Damn, somehow I had Java in mind. Anyway it can be done in JS also. See update answer now.

Comment: Thanks - trying at the moment, JavaScript struggles with the group `Invalid regular expression: /(?s)at (?:(?!MooD)[\s\S])*/: Invalid group`. I'm guessing it's not a fully implemented version of RegEx

Comment: Sorry another typo, `(?s)` shouldn't be there (corrected)

Comment: Ah - I missed the `$` off one of them, seems the last approach using the word boundary is happy.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to do this with regex, but here is a non-regex option:

```
public static string GetMooDStackTrace(string stackTrace)
{
    var lines = stackTrace.Split('\n');
    int lastLineWithMood = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("MooD"))
            lastLineWithMood = i;
    }

    return string.Join("\n", lines, 0, lastLineWithMood + 1);
}
```

From your input, produces:

```
at MooD.LandscapeExplorer.Controllers.LandscapeController.GetContextInstanceCount(BusinessContext context) in C:\Source\MooDEdge\Code\MooD16\MooD.LandscapeExplorer\Controllers\LandscapeController.cs:line 143
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__1`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MooD.LandscapeExplorer.Controllers.LandscapeController.ProcessContext(String[] types, String[] instances, QueryFilter[] filters) in C:\Source\MooDEdge\Code\MooD16\MooD.LandscapeExplorer\Controllers\LandscapeController.cs:line 125
```

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear that the RegEx is being executed in JavaScript.

Comment: Should be relatively easy to port over, but I'm not fluent in JS so I won't try. I'll leave this up for future generations I guess.

Comment: Yeah - I see it could potentially be useful for others